# Import excel data and keep date time

Tags: excel, python-2.7

thanks in advance for your help. i'm importing data from excel using openpyxl though i'd like to get strings into datetime, below is the code i'm using:

```
import openpyxl, pprint, datetime
print ('Opening workbook...')
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('ACLogs_test_Conv2.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print sheet
ACLogsData = {}
print ('Reading rows...')
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row +1):
    pangalan  = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    dates = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    time = sheet['E' + str(row)].value
    ACLogsData.setdefault(pangalan,{})
    ACLogsData[pangalan].setdefault(dates,{})
    ACLogsData[pangalan][dates].setdefault(time)
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data. What format is the date in ? See [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and [converting python string to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use datetime.strptime()

```
FMT = '%H:%M' # Whatever format your times are in

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row +1):
    pangalan  = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    dates = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    time = datetime.strptime(sheet['E' + str(row)].value, FMT)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this is me being a noob appreciating the help

Comment: thanks, first time asking and didnt know i have to do that!